# Django how to upload file directly to 3rd-part storage server, like Cloudinary, S3

Tags: django

Now, I have realized the uploading process is like that:

**1. Generate the HTTP request object, and set the value to request.FILE by using uploadhandler.**

**2. In the views.py, the instance of FieldFile which is the mirror of FileField will call the storage.save() to upload file.**

---

So, as you see, django always use the cache or disk to pass the data, if your file is too large, it will cost too much time.

And the design I want to figure this problem is to custom an uploadhandler which will call storage.save() by using input raw data. The only question is how can I modify the actions of FileField?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://bipuljain.com/blog/image-file-upload-with-django-11 Check this out

Comment: Thank you, and I have to admit that I do not use the S3 storage, but I know the best method always same.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this package

Add direct uploads to AWS S3 functionality with a progress bar to file input fields.

https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct

Comment: I haven't used it, but here's a similar lib for Google cloud: https://github.com/koendewit/django-direct-cloud-upload

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following packages
https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary
http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Comment: I am using the pycloudinary now, but maybe this is a good chance to learn those with code level. I need to make sure that if it can transfer file directly( although I doubt that because they use it in storage level).

Comment: `django-storoges` will upload the file first to your django server and then from there to the cloud storage. Cloudinary docs have a section about direct upload https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_image_and_video_upload#direct_uploading_from_the_browser but are not very clear. We can see in the lib that some django helpers for this usage are provided though https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/master/cloudinary/templatetags/cloudinary.py#L49